# Modify x-axis labels in Kibana 4.4.2

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using Kibana 4.4.2 Build 9732, and I've created a line-chart visualization.

Visualization splits data by hours in day, so **labels look like:**

```
2016-04-13 00:00:00 - 2016-04-13 01:00:00 

2016-04-13 01:00:00 - 2016-04-13 02:00:00
```

**I would like to label those like:**

```
"First hour"

"Second hour"
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: That is slated for the [4.5 release](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2386)

Comment: @Val Thanks.. i think i'll wait

Comment: Kibana 4.5 has been released some time back.