# Kibana: is it possible to change the label of my axes?

Tags: kibana

I am currently using Kibana 4.4.2 and I can't change the label of my axes. I know that the question was already asked last year ([Modify x-axis labels in Kibana 4.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591814/modify-x-axis-labels-in-kibana-4-4-2)) but I don't know if it is available in a more recent version.

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Joe

Comment: available in Kibana 4.5.1

Comment: I'm on 5.0.0 and not seeing those features.